# Is there a way to run a script in Windows 10 that changes the language of a program or app?

Tags: windows-10, script, language, japanese, english

I work in Japan and in my laboratory there are many shared PCs (attached to instruments). Most of them are Japanese language PCs and the programs and apps installed open to the language of the OS by default. Is there a way to write a script that can "fool" the program into thinking that the language of the OS is set to English so that I can use the program in English without having to change the entire OS to English through the Language and Region settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a third-party product for that, for example
[Locale Emulator](https://github.com/xupefei/Locale-Emulator):

> Locale Emulator is a tool similar to AppLocale and NTLEA, providing a simulation function that can make an application recognize your OS as in a language other than the real one. It is quite useful when you are trying to play country-specific games.

[image]